# jQuery infinite slider plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a nightmare trying to get a plugin working with my script.

It seems that on page load the jQuery selector isnt seeing my div as nothing happens at all.

It should be a simple row of images that can be scrolled through left and right.

Ive put all of my code on one page here, if anybody has any advice on whats going wrong id greatly appreciate it! thanks!

http://liamg.co.uk/test.html

---

Worth noting, console throws no errors neither

Answer (score 0):

At `jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true")` try putting true without the quotes (`jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth(true)`).

Answer (score 0):

In your page, you've got a call:

```
    var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true")
```

that should be:

```
    var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth(true)
```

(note the lack of quotes around true)